# Babelify the files in place, in multiple directories

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

How can I use [`babel`](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile the JavaScript files containing ES6 stuff, in different directories? I want the result to be in the same directories (e.g. having `foo/bar/index.js`, I want to get the ES5 code in the same file, by **overriding** it).

To override one directory I use:

```
 babel lib/ -d lib
```

This works for one folder (overrides all the content in the `lib` directory).

How can I do the same for two or more directories? For example, how can I do that for `lib/` and `bin/`?

Comment: Another solution, may be to put all the files and folders in parent folder and then apply ``babel parent_folder/ -d parent_folder`` to the parent_folder :)

Comment: Why would you want to do this anyway ?

Comment: @naomik I'm setting up a tool that would automate the `npm publish` thing so I publish on npm the transpiled code. I want to keep the file structure and after `npm publish` to `git checkout .`.

Comment: There's countless ways to build/package your code that don't involve destroying the source files and rolling them back with git...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK the [babel CLI](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) isn't complex enough to support this use-case in a single command. However you could concatenate two commands to achieve the same result:

```
babel lib/ -d lib && babel bin/ -d bin
```

Or you could write a script that does this for you, using gulp or another build tool of your choice. For example (untested):

```
gulp.task('default', () =>
  gulp.src(['bin/**/*.js', 'lib/**/*.js'], { base: './' })
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
)
```

Comment: I guess I will just end with `babel . -d . --ignore node_modules` or so. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

[The codemod CLI](https://github.com/codemod-js/codemod/blob/master/packages/cli/README.md) is perfect for this.

It will just modify your files in place:

```
codemod --plugin babel-transformer.js src/**/*.js
```